# SAX parsing android : how to get child nodes

Tags: android, parsing, get, sax, child-nodes

I want to get data from XML file :https://www.vietcombank.com.vn/exchangerates/ExrateXML.aspx

the error is i can get the last element USD and pass the others. Please help me

here is my all class:
Exrate.java

```
 public class Exrate {
    String CurrencyCode;
    String CurrencyName;
    String Buy;
    String Transfer;
    String Sell;

    public Exrate(){}

    public String getCurrencyCode() {
        return CurrencyCode;
    }
    public void setCurrencyCode(String CurrencyCode) {
        this.CurrencyCode = CurrencyCode;
    }
    //
    public String getCurrencyName(){
        return CurrencyName;
    }
    public void setCurrencyName(String CurrencyName){
        this.CurrencyName=CurrencyName;
    }
    //
    public String getBuy(){
        return Buy;
    }
    public void setBuy(String Buy ){
        this.Buy=Buy;
    }
    //
    public String getTransfer(){
        return Transfer;
    }
    public void setTransfer(String Transfer ){
        this.Transfer=Transfer;
    }
    //
    public String getSell(){
        return Sell;
    }
    public void setSell(String Sell ){
        this.Sell=Sell;
    }
}
```

ExrateList.java

```
    public class ExrateList {
    String Datetime;
    Exrate exrate;
    public ExrateList(){}

    public String getDatetime(){
        return Datetime;
    }
    public void setDatetime(String DateTime){
        this.Datetime=DateTime;
    }
    //
    public Exrate getExrate(){
        return exrate;
    }
    public void setExrate(Exrate exrate){
        this.exrate=exrate;
    }

}
```

SaxHandler.java

```
    public class SaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    String reading;
    ArrayList<ExrateList> exrateLists;
    ExrateList exrateList;
    Exrate exrate;
    public SaxHandler() {
        exrateLists = new ArrayList<ExrateList>();
    }



    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ExrateList")){
                exrateLists=new ArrayList<>();
                exrateList=new ExrateList();
        }
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Exrate")){
            exrate=new Exrate();
            exrate.setCurrencyCode(attributes.getValue("CurrencyCode"));
            exrate.setCurrencyName(attributes.getValue("CurrencyName"));
            exrate.setBuy(attributes.getValue("Buy"));
            exrate.setTransfer(attributes.getValue("Transfer"));
            exrate.setSell(attributes.getValue("Sell"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ExrateList")){
            if (exrateLists!=null){
                exrateLists.add(exrateList);
                exrateList=null;
            }
        }
         if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("DateTime")){
            exrateList.setDatetime(reading);
        }
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Exrate")){
            exrateList.setExrate(exrate);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        reading=new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    public List<ExrateList> getExrateLists() {
        return exrateLists;
    }
}
```

MySaxParser.java

```
    public class MySaxParser {
    public List<ExrateList> XMLparse(InputStream is) {
        List<ExrateList> exrateLists = null;
        try {
            // create a XMLReader from SAXParser
            XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
            // create a SAXXMLHandler
            SaxHandler saxHandler = new SaxHandler();
            // store handler in XMLReader
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(saxHandler);
            // the process starts
            xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(is));
            // get the `Employee list`
            exrateLists =saxHandler.getExrateLists();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("XML", "SAXXMLParser: parse() failed");
        }

        // return Employee list
        return exrateLists;
    }
}

MainActivity.java

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView ngay, chuoi;
    String duongdan = "https://www.vietcombank.com.vn/exchangerates/ExrateXML.aspx";
    List<ExrateList> exrateLists = new ArrayList<ExrateList>();
    String datetime;
    String macode="";
    String tencode="";
    String mua="";
    InputStream is;
    URL url;
    URLConnection connection;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ngay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        chuoi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Task a=new Task();
        a.execute();
    }

    class Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                url=new URL(duongdan);
                connection=url.openConnection();
                is=connection.getInputStream();
                MySaxParser mySaxParser=new MySaxParser();
                exrateLists=mySaxParser.XMLparse(is);
                //
                datetime=exrateLists.get(0).getDatetime();

                for(int i=0;i<exrateLists.size();i++) {

                    macode+=exrateLists.get(i).getExrate().getCurrencyCode();
                    tencode+= exrateLists.get(i).getExrate().getCurrencyName()+"\n";
                    mua+= exrateLists.get(i).getExrate().getBuy();

                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            ngay.setText(datetime);
            chuoi.setText(macode+" "+tencode+" "+mua);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [simple framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) to show this example that how you can read the xml tag.

Create two classes which will help us create the Object which will act as Model classes.

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

/**
 * Created by Pankaj Nimgade on 29-01-2016.
 */
@Root (name = "Exrate", strict = false)
public class Exrate {
    @Attribute(required = false)
    private String CurrencyCode;

    @Attribute(required = false)
    private String CurrencyName;

    @Attribute(required = false)
    private String Buy;

    @Attribute(required = false)
    private String Transfer;

    @Attribute(required = false)
    private String Sell;

    public Exrate() {
    }

    public Exrate(String currencyCode, String currencyName, String buy, String transfer, String sell) {
        CurrencyCode = currencyCode;
        CurrencyName = currencyName;
        Buy = buy;
        Transfer = transfer;
        Sell = sell;
    }

    public String getCurrencyCode() {
        return CurrencyCode;
    }

    public String getCurrencyName() {
        return CurrencyName;
    }

    public String getBuy() {
        return Buy;
    }

    public String getTransfer() {
        return Transfer;
    }

    public String getSell() {
        return Sell;
    }
}
```

> ExrateList

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Pankaj Nimgade on 29-01-2016.
 */
@Root (name = "ExrateList", strict = false)
public class ExrateList {
    @Element(required = false)
    private String DateTime;

    @ElementList (inline = true,required= false)
    private List<Exrate> Exrate;

    @Element(required = false)
    private String Source;

    public ExrateList() {
    }

    public ExrateList(String dateTime, String source) {
        DateTime = dateTime;
        Source = source;
    }

    public String getDateTime() {
        return DateTime;
    }

    public List<Exrate> getList() {
        return Exrate;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return Source;
    }
}
```

now you can test the code

```
public class ReadXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Path paths = Paths.get("");
            String project_Path = paths.toAbsolutePath().toString();
            System.out.println("" + project_Path);
            File file = new File(project_Path + "\\excel_files\\some.xml");
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();

            ExrateList example = serializer.read(ExrateList.class, file);
            System.out.println("" + example.getDateTime());
            for (Exrate exrate:example.getList()) {
                System.out.println(""+exrate.getCurrencyName()+"\t "+exrate.getCurrencyCode()+"\t "+exrate.getTransfer()+"\t "+exrate.getBuy()+"\t "+exrate.getSell());
            }
            System.out.println("" + example.getSource());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> Outout

```
1/29/2016 4:11:40 PM
AUST.DOLLAR AUD 15731.66 15637.27
CANADIAN DOLLAR CAD 15768.98 15627.06
SWISS FRANCE CHF 21700.14 21548.24
DANISH KRONE DKK 3191.26 0
EURO EUR 24068.25 23996.05
BRITISH POUND GBP 31737.38 31515.22
HONGKONG DOLLAR HKD 2831.9 2812.08
INDIAN RUPEE INR 320.61 0
JAPANESE YEN JPY 182.95 181.12
SOUTH KOREAN WON KRW 18.48 0
KUWAITI DINAR KWD 72009.45 0
MALAYSIAN RINGGIT MYR 5340.84 0
NORWEGIAN KRONER NOK 2536.44 0
RUSSIAN RUBLE RUB 267.7 0
SAUDI RIAL SAR 5745.75 0
SWEDISH KRONA SEK 2573.7 0
SINGAPORE DOLLAR SGD 15520.44 15411.8
THAI BAHT THB 609.21 609.21
US DOLLAR USD 22165 22165
Joint Stock Commercial Bank for Foreign Trade of Vietnam - Vietcombank
```

Comment: Thank you.But the SaxHandler.java and MySaxParser.java.Can you fix it for me? I don't know how to fix it right

Comment: @BenPham, what you can do is get the String from the response from the API, open a inputStream and make file, simple framework will handle the rest of the work

Comment: I did it in MainActivity and nothing happend. Here is the code:in AsyncTask  url=new URL(duongdan);
                connection=url.openConnection();
                is=connection.getInputStream();
                Serializer serializer = new Persister();
                ExrateList example = serializer.read(ExrateList.class, duongdan);
                a=example.getDateTime();
                System.out.println("" + example.getDateTime());

Comment: @BenPham, Where is the code, do make sure you add simple framwork library to the project

Comment: Yes. I have imported the libs

Comment: @BenPham, i found solution for you, you can provide a inputStream instead of a file

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally success. Thank you Pankaj Nimgade

Comment: @BenPham, I am glad that, I could help, I was about to write you a tutorial, apparently I don't need to. Have a good day to you!